# filter-branch wont delete orphan branches

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-filter-branch

I have a large and old project and I want to turn a folder into a submodule

I used

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <folder name> -- --all
```

to seperate it from the rest of the project and keep all the history that's relevent for it

It did what I want but there were a few commits that weren't related to the folder
after a bit of research I discovered that all of the unrelated commits were from two orphan branches

I did more research and discovered that the commits of the orphan branches were included in

```
git rev-list --all
```

The question is, why weren't the orphan branches deleted if they didn't have any relation to the folder I specified?

and if I can't remove their history in the same command, what can I do to delete all of the orphan branches history?

**Edit:**
I already tried with the `--prune-empty` option to no avail

Comment: Anything typed after `--` is interpreted as a filename. It means "the options end here".

Comment: @RomainValeri I dont think this is the case in filter-branch, refer to the git docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#git-filter-branch-ltrev-listoptionsgt82308203

Comment: You're absolutely right ^^ talk about a confusing choice of syntax... anyway, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to run the following command:

```
git push origin : <orphan_branch_name> --force
```

or, alternatively - before running `filter-branch command, run this:

```
git remote in `git branch -r | grep -v "<orpan_branch_names>"; do git checkout --track $remote; done
```

where `<orpan_branch_names>` are the orphan branch names seperated with `|`(or)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the `--prune-empty` option, it will remove commits that leave the the subdirectory untouched.

Comment: I tried that already, it didnt change anything. and even if i didn't add it the branch should still be there, just empty